# What TeX engine is recommended?

Tags: formatting, plain-tex

I am a very long-time user of TeXtures, publishing multiple books using PlainTex (figures in Adobe Illustrator) with TeXtures.  Since TeXtures will no longer work with Macs (I'm currently using Ventura 13.1), I need to move on.  Ideally it would be an implementation that would accept my old TeX files with minimal changes.  What would you recommend?  Thanks.

Comment: Get MacTeX (texlive mac flavoured) if you just need 8 bit fonts (as you used with textures) use pdftex, if you want to use Unicode,use lua(hb)tex, but you don't need to decide, most people use multiple engines. MacTeX has all pdftex, luatex, luahbtex,xetex, ptex, uptex,...

Answer (score 3):

Get MacTeX (Mac flavoured texlive).

If you just need 8 bit fonts (as you used with textures) use pdftex, if you want to use Unicode, use lua(hb)tex, but you don't need to decide: most people use multiple engines. MacTeX has all of pdftex, luatex, luahbtex, xetex, ptex, uptex,...

Most documents will "just work" however the extent to which you need to update documents depends on how you coded your original documents.

For example image inclusion,  if you used some macro set such as

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{file.eps}
```

which comes from LaTeX but is also available for plain, then you do not need to do anything at all, the macros will detect that pdflatex rather than textures is used and use appropriate back end definitions.

If on the other hand your documents have textures specific `\special` directly in the text for example

```
\special{illustration file.eps scaled 0.5}
```

then you would need to replace the special by equivalent markup for pdftex or luatex or whichever engine you choose, or better use some generic markup such as `\includgraphics` (or psfig or pstricks variants) so the document will work on all current engines.

Similar remarks apply to color or other back end features.